# Why's 人 (human) the radical and semantic component of 儲 "to store, collect"?

Tags: etymology

How do  human beings semantically appertain to the verbs for "to store, collect"?

I cite Axel Schuessler, *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*  (2007). First I pinpointed 儲 at the bottom of p 192, but it forwards you to p 626.

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is the red underline?

Comment: @BoomingBones Sorry! No red underline intended here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"儲" and"偫" are alliteration in ancient China.- Annotation of Origin of Chinese Characters written by 段玉裁 in Qing Dynasty
(从人。諸聲...儲偫爲雙聲。--清代 段玉裁《說文解字注》)
http://www.shuowen.org/view/5005

Both of them have a meaning of "waiting for sb/sth" and then extended to "store / collect".

Like the previous answer "從人，示人所爲也" indicates, the reason why "儲" refers to "Person Radical/Man Radical"  is that it's a word to express humans' acts/behavior.

Here's the explanation of "Person Radical/Man Radical" but in Chinese, anyway. In sum, the words originally and directly related to humans, personality, human acts, human power, the human-liked might be classified as Person Radical.
https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA%E9%83%A8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because humans do it? See [this picture](https://bkimg.cdn.bcebos.com/pic/4e4a20a4462309f790521276eb471bf3d7ca7bcb7837?x-bce-process=image/watermark,image_d2F0ZXIvYmFpa2U4MA==,g_7,xp_5,yp_5/format,f_auto)
from https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%82%A8/2610740.

It says "從人，示人所爲也", which means "..., represent that human do it".

Also, there's a word called "儲君", which means "Heir of the king". Often used in ancient China. My guess for the use of "儲" in this word is you store one human as heir to prepare for the death of the king.

As you can see, now you store human. (attention, only guess!) It may be helpful for your understanding of the character if you learn words that use the character.